# How to use Power Query to find a word in a PDF document and pull a table out

Tags: sql, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to import multiple PDF tables into PowerQuery but the table appear on different pages. In one pdf, the table can appear on Page 5 while the other the table can appear on page 10. In this case the table headers are the same. How can I use PowerQuery to find this table header and pull these tables into excel?

Thanks for the anticipated help.

Comment: Post sample data and desired output

Comment: Not sure how I can post a sample data. But my question is on how to use power query to pull tables from multiple pdf when the tables do not occur on consistent pages.

Comment: If I had a sample to work with and desired output, I'd attempt create some code for you, but alas, I do not

Comment: https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1410191-import-tables-from-pdf-into-excel.html#post5858080

Comment: I posted it in this link above...thanks for your anticipated help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work on your three sample files

```
let PullPDF = (variable)=> let
Source = Pdf.Tables(File.Contents(variable)),
List = List.Union(List.Transform(Source[Data], each Table.ColumnNames(_))), 
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(Source, "Data", List,List)   ,
// assume all data above row containing word Volume is garbage
Row=Table.RemoveFirstN(#"Expanded Data",List.PositionOf(#"Expanded Data"[Column2],"Volume")),
#"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(Row,{"Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column4", "Column5", "Column6", "Column7"}),
#"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Removed Other Columns", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
// change or remove next row as needed based on real column names and formats
#"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"A3 Unit", type text}, {"Volume", Int64.Type}, {"∆V", Int64.Type}, {"Method", type text}, {"Volume_1", Int64.Type}, {"∆V_2", Int64.Type}, {"Delta#(lf)Volume", Int64.Type}})
in  #"Changed Type",


Source2 = Folder.Files("c:\temp\"),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source2, each ([Extension] = ".pdf")),
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Data", each PullPDF([Folder Path]&[Name])),
List = List.Union(List.Transform(#"Added Custom"[Data], each Table.ColumnNames(_))), 
#"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "Data", List,List)   
in  #"Expanded Data"
```

I looked on the other site since I was bored, but really, requiring people to log into another site to help you on this one is not optimal

Comment: Please I added another related question with regards to the modification of the PowerQuery here

https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/1410207-import-various-tables-with-different-formats-from-pdf-into-excel-and-arranged.html#post5858168

Comment: I have upvoted it. Thanks for the answer. I will try to add a new question

Comment: Please can you answer like you did for me last time and post the results here?

Comment: Create a new question and I'll post the answer there. Thanks. You cannot change the requirements on this one

Comment: See email on other forum.  If this does not work, then you need to provide real PDF samples